# Word for "to cheat fate" or "to seize/act on a moment"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that means a person seized an opportunity or acted on some sort of signal/sign in non-ideal circumstances.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! In the future, could you please capitalize and such? This is not your typical forum.

Comment: More context, please. I don't understand exactly what circumstance you want this word for.

Answer (score 2):

A noun to describe someone who seizes an opportunity is an [opportunist](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/opportunist).

You could say that such a person:

*acts opportunistically*

*takes advantage* of a situation

*capitalizes* on an opportunity

*exploits* a situation

etc.